# StringByAppendingPathComponent() and WriteToFile()

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to learn Swift 3 with translating a code from Swift 2. In swift 2, I see the code like this:

```
return fullPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(name)
```

But, when I try in Swift 3, I've got similiar code, but like this:

```
return fullPath.strings(byAppendingPaths: [name])
```

The issue is, return type in the 1st code is String (and that's the output I need from the lesson I learn), but return type in 2nd code should be [String].

The other issue is, in Swift 2 the code should be:

```
imgData?.WriteToFile(fullPath, atomicaly:Bool)
```

But in Swift 3, I only can input code like this:

```
imgData.Write(to: URL , option: WritingOption) throws
```

But in some examples, there's .Write(toFile: , atomically:) but I can't find it in Xcode.

Am I translating incorrectly or using both Swift 2 and Swift 3 incorrectly?

Comment: You want `fullPath.appendingPathComponent(name)`

Comment: @dan thanks for help, and its works..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Regarding the first part of your question**, as dan stated in the comments you should be using `fullPath.appendingPathComponent(name)` instead.

**Regarding your second question:**

The main difference between `writeToFile` and `write(to:` is the fact that the first is for `String`s and the seconds is for `NSData`.

**Somewhat related:**

According to the [NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#/)

In iOS 2.0+ you have:

```
write(to:atomically:)
```

and

```
write(toFile:atomically:)
```

Given:

> Since at present only file:// URLs are supported, there is no
>   difference between this method and writeToFile:atomically:, except for
>   the type of the first argument.

None of this has changed in Swift 3 according to the [Swift Changelog](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution).

Comment: I find it unfortunate that your answer only echoes a comment without adding anything.

Comment: i see from my lesson example (write in swift 2), they using imgData?.WriteToFile(fullPath, atomicaly:Bool) . imgData is NSdata?. fullPath is path in string. Then i tried it in xcode 8 with swift 3, when i input imgData, there's no write(toFile: String, atomically:) option in autocomplete. i should choose write(toFile) cause my filePath is String. but the only option i had is only write(to:). do u know how to solved it? @WMios

Comment: @RoccoBerry, why not convert the String to NSData? `let data = imgData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

Comment: @WMios i finally using Write(to:URL) and converting string to url. and thats works.... anyway thanks a lot :D